# Setting up a postgresql testing database for pytest suite for django project

Tags: django, postgresql, pytest-django

I am relatively new to Python/Django and Pytest. I have a couple of methods that I would like to test that require changes to be made to my database. I have been utilizing fixtures to set up and tear down my database per session. However, my pytests want to keep using my original database, which defeats the purpose of having a test database (I am getting access denied anyway saying "I cannot access this database in Testing"). I believe this is due to my database router I have setup. I plan to have a database per app in the project, so my logic is `"app_name == database_name"`.

Below is what I have for my setup and teardown:

```
import pytest
import psycopg2
import os


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def postgresql_db():
    # Set up the test database connection
    db_name = 'test_db'
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', 'postgres'),
        user=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'postgres'),
        password=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', ''),
        host=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432'),
    )

    # Create the test database
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name};")

    yield connection

    # Close the connection and clean up the test database
    connection.close()
    with psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', 'postgres'),
        user=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'postgres'),
        password=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', ''),
        host=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PORT', '5432'),
    ) as cleanup_connection:
        with cleanup_connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {db_name};")
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a more standard way to test methods that can save to a database?

I need education.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is just a DB to run tests with, you don't need these manual setup and teardown steps. One easy way to create a test db that will get all migrations every time automatically, is to have a separate test settings file with something like:

`settings_test.py`:

```py
from .settings import *

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

Add your relevant postgres config here instead of sqlite and ensure it points to your test database. Then invoke your tests with that settings file:

`$ python3 manage.py test --settings=myapp.settings_test`

That's it, no connection, create DB, clean up, etc. code required. If you need multiple databases, just keep adding to the DATABASES dictionary. Django docs have more tips for [testing with multiple db's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#controlling-creation-order-for-test-databases).